# Prisma.js: We found changes that cannot be executed

Tags: node.js, express, orm, prisma, prisma2

I've used prisma.js as an ORM in my project.

After executing the `npx prisma migrate dev --name rename_and_add_some_columns`,
I got this error:

> We found changes that cannot be executed

Error Details:

> Step 1 Added the required column `CategoryId` to the `Post` table
> without a default value. There are 2 rows in this table, it is not
> possible to execute this step.   • Step 1 Added the required column
> `ModifiedDate` to the `Post` table without a default value. There are
> 2 rows in this table, it is not possible to execute this step.   •
> Step 2 Added the required column `ModifiedDate` to the `Profile` table
> without a default value. There are 1 rows in this table, it is not
> possible to execute this step.   • Step 4 Added the required column
> `ModifiedDate` to the `User` table without a default value. There are
> 2 rows in this table, it is not possible to execute this step.
>
> You can use prisma migrate dev --create-only to create the migration
> file, and manually modify it to address the underlying issue(s). Then
> run prisma migrate dev to apply it and verify it works.

How can I solve it?

// This is my Prisma schema file,

```
datasource db {
  provider = "mysql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

model Category {
  Id           Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  CreatedDate  DateTime @default(now())
  ModifiedDate DateTime @updatedAt
  Title        String   @db.VarChar(50)
  IsActive     Boolean
  Posts        Post[]
}

model Post {
  Id                 Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  CreatedDate        DateTime  @default(now())
  ModifiedDate       DateTime  @updatedAt
  Title              String    @db.VarChar(255)
  Description        String?
  IsPublished        Boolean   @default(false)
  IsActive           Boolean   @default(true)
  IsActiveNewComment Boolean   @default(true)
  Author             User      @relation(fields: [AuthorId], references: [Id])
  AuthorId           Int
  Comment            Comment[]
  Tag                Tag[]     @relation("TagToPost", fields: [tagId], references: [Id])
  tagId              Int?
  Category           Category  @relation(fields: [CategoryId], references: [Id])
  CategoryId         Int
}

model User {
  Id           Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  CreatedDate  DateTime  @default(now())
  ModifiedDate DateTime  @updatedAt
  Email        String    @unique
  Name         String?
  Posts        Post[]
  Profile      Profile?
  Comments     Comment[]
}

model Profile {
  Id           Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  CreatedDate  DateTime @default(now())
  ModifiedDate DateTime @updatedAt
  Bio          String?
  User         User     @relation(fields: [UserId], references: [Id])
  UserId       Int      @unique
}

model Comment {
  Id           Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  CreatedDate  DateTime @default(now())
  ModifiedDate DateTime @updatedAt
  Comment      String
  WrittenBy    User     @relation(fields: [WrittenById], references: [Id])
  WrittenById  Int
  Post         Post     @relation(fields: [PostId], references: [Id])
  PostId       Int
}

model Tag {
  Id           Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  CreatedDate  DateTime @default(now())
  ModifiedDate DateTime @updatedAt
  Title        String   @unique
  Posts        Post[]   @relation("TagToPost")
}
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In order to run this migration, you need to:

1. Create the fields first as optional and then run `migrate`
2. Fill the fields first with the required date.
3. Remove the optional (`?`) from the field.

Prisma automatically adds `@updatedAt` (it's not done at the database level) so these steps need to be followed.

Comment: Why should I do step 3 (Remove the optional (?) from the field)?
Without doing it, it works.

Comment: If you want it to be required, if not then it's totally fine.

Answer (score 5):

Alternatively, you can just add `@default(now())` to your `ModifiedDate` properties. So, for instance, the `Category` model would be:

```
model Category {
  Id           Int      @id @default(autoincrement())
  CreatedDate  DateTime @default(now())
  ModifiedDate DateTime @default(now()) @updatedAt
  Title        String   @db.VarChar(50)
  IsActive     Boolean
  Posts        Post[]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In thePost model, I changed the `Category` to `Category?` and `Int` to `Int?`

Also, I changed `Datetime` in ModifiedDate to `Datetime?`

```
model Category {
  Id           Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  CreatedDate  DateTime  @default(now())
  ModifiedDate DateTime? @updatedAt
  Title        String    @db.VarChar(50)
  IsActive     Boolean
  Posts        Post[]
}

model Post {
  Id                 Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  CreatedDate        DateTime  @default(now())
  ModifiedDate       DateTime? @updatedAt
  Title              String    @db.VarChar(255)
  Description        String?
  IsPublished        Boolean   @default(false)
  IsActive           Boolean   @default(true)
  IsActiveNewComment Boolean   @default(true)
  Author             User      @relation(fields: [AuthorId], references: [Id])
  AuthorId           Int
  Comment            Comment[]
  Tag                Tag[]     @relation("TagToPost", fields: [tagId], references: [Id])
  tagId              Int?
  Category           Category? @relation(fields: [CategoryId], references: [Id])
  CategoryId         Int?
}

model User {
  Id           Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  CreatedDate  DateTime  @default(now())
  ModifiedDate DateTime? @updatedAt
  Email        String    @unique
  Name         String?
  Posts        Post[]
  Profile      Profile?
  Comments     Comment[]
}

model Profile {
  Id           Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  CreatedDate  DateTime  @default(now())
  ModifiedDate DateTime? @updatedAt
  Bio          String?
  User         User      @relation(fields: [UserId], references: [Id])
  UserId       Int       @unique
}

model Comment {
  Id           Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  CreatedDate  DateTime  @default(now())
  ModifiedDate DateTime? @updatedAt
  Comment      String
  WrittenBy    User      @relation(fields: [WrittenById], references: [Id])
  WrittenById  Int
  Post         Post      @relation(fields: [PostId], references: [Id])
  PostId       Int
}

model Tag {
  Id           Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  CreatedDate  DateTime  @default(now())
  ModifiedDate DateTime? @updatedAt
  Title        String    @unique
  Posts        Post[]    @relation("TagToPost")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I retroactively added the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` fields, and I don't want to provide an `updatedAt` value for existing fields, but I can live with the fact that `now()` will become the default `createdAt` for existing values.

Add a `?` question mark behind the `DateTime?` of the `updatedAt` field, making it optional. The field will be `null` by default when you migrate your schema but will populate as expected on subsequent updates of the row.

```
model MyModel {
...
    createdAt   DateTime  @default(now())
    updatedAt   DateTime? @updatedAt
}
```

Answer (score 0):

perform two operations

1. "yarn prisma db push".

and after following the commands

2. "yarn prisma migrate dev"